# Thumbnail Script Not Creating Square Images

Tags: php, image

I'm using a thumbnail script that is supposed to create thumbnails for images in my gallery directory. It works great. But one issue. The images are coming out rectangular instead of square. I need the images to come out square. I have the width set to 150 and the height set to 150. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is a pre-written script I am using that can be found at http://www.foliopages.com/php-photo-gallery-no-database [Not my site, this is the source of the script]

This is the first half of the thumbnail script(there are other functions in between these two parts):

```
$thumb_width   = '150';      // width of thumbnails
$thumb_height  = '150';       // height of thumbnails
$extensions    = array(".jpg",".png",".gif",".JPG",".PNG",".GIF"); // allowed extensions in photo gallery


// create thumbnails from images
function make_thumb($folder,$src,$dest,$thumb_width) {

    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder.'/'.$src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    $thumb_height = floor($height*($thumb_width/$width));

    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);

    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);

    imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest,100);

}
```

And the second part:

```
   $thumb = $src_folder.'/thumbs/'.$file;
           if (!file_exists($thumb)) {
              make_thumb($src_folder,$file,$thumb,$thumb_width); 

           }
```

Comment: Replace the line containg `floor` with `$thumb_height=$thumb_width;`

Comment: Mind putting that as an answer so I can accept it? :) It worked.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you calculate a value for `$thumb_height` in the line

```
$thumb_height = floor($height*($thumb_width/$width));
```

Replace that line with this one to make the thumb square:

```
$thumb_height=$thumb_width;
```